# Data visualization using seek bar

Tags: data-visualization, seekbar

I have data in a table with timestamp and value of a recorded parameter for, let's just say, 1 hour. Values are recorded multiple times per second.

I need to construct a music player's seek bar style setup using which user can see the values at various times. It is like playing a song but instead of playing song it displays values.

Please see the below image for better understanding of the program's goal:

[Data table and data visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps6Ru.png)

The program needs to accomplish below tasks:

1. When the user clicks play button values from the table are extracted and displayed.
2. User should be able to use the seek bar to jump back and forth and see the values at different times. For example if the user records the values for half hour, he should be able to use the seek bar to see the values at 0:11:45, 0:19:34, 0:5:42 and so on.

I am developing this for ios using swift.

What is the best way to construct the seek bar and synchronize it with the data in the table?